# Select All using SQL subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

I have two tables like this

```
create table department(
Dno int primary key,
name varchar(50) not null
)


create table employee(
empid int primary key,
name varchar(50) not null,
sal decimal(7,2) not null,
dno int foreign key references department(Dno))
```

I want to get the same result of the following query using a SQL subquery.

```
SELECT e.Name, e.Sal, d.Dno, d.Name
FROM Employee e,
     Department d
WHERE e.Dno = d.Dno
  AND e.name = 'aa'
```

Following is what I tried.

```
SELECT Name, Sal
FROM Employee
WHERE Name= 'aa' AND Dno IN
    (SELECT Dno, name
     FROM Department)
```

This gives following error.

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: Just do `select dno from department` in you subquery, yo don't need the `name` column to be selected

Comment: @msanz If I want to show all of the two tables using subquery how can I do?

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: why don't you just use join ?

Comment: can you provide sample data and desired output ?

Comment: On a side note: you should certainly avoid the use of [Old Style JOINS](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) and use explicit `INNER JOIN`s

Comment: Your first query selects columns from both tables. Your second selects only Employee columns. With a sub-query in the WHERE clause, you can never get it's columns in the result.

Comment: The main question is: Why do you want to use a sub-query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subquery should only select a single column and return a list.

```
SELECT Name, Sal
FROM Employee
WHERE Name= 'aa' AND Dno IN
    (SELECT Dno FROM Department)
```

On the other hand, you cannot get columns from `Department` into the result by making a subquery.

The best way to achieve what you're trying to get is by joining tables:

```
SELECT e.Name, e.Sal, d.Dno, d.Name
FROM Employee e 
INNER JOIN Department d ON e.Dno = d.Dno
WHERE e.name = 'aa'
```

Comment: If I want to show all of the two tables using subquery how can I do?

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage you can't. Subqueries are not intended for that purpose. You'll need to do what you're currently doing or just `JOIN` both tables

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Name, Sal
FROM Employee
WHERE Name= 'aa' AND Dno IN
    (SELECT Dno
      FROM Department)
```

You need to remove the name in the subquery. When executing a query, think as each value received by the subquery will be compared with the value of your 'main' query.

If you have the following record in employees

```
ID   Name   Sal   Dno
1    Bob    3000     3
2    Alice  3000     2
```

And the following record in Department

```
Dno Name          
1  Advertisement 
2  Programming   
3  Analysement
```

You can't of course compare the value 3 of Bob with {3, Analysement}. Subqueries are usually used for filtering your rows, not for wanting to display extra values as a join can do.

Answer (score 1):

Subquery can be used to fetch data from multiple RELATED tables.
It can't be used to join two tables.
If u want to show multiple tables, you either have to use JOIN or UNION.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put two columns in subquery

```
SELECT Name, Sal
FROM Employee
WHERE Name= 'aa' AND Dno IN
    (SELECT Dno
      FROM Department)
```

Comment: If I want to show all of the two tables using subquery how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Better to use 'EXISTS' instead of 'IN' clause. Here is the script

```
SELECT Name, Sal
FROM Employee e
WHERE Name= 'aa' 
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Department d WHERE e.Dno=d.Dno)
```